# ICEFaces 1.8 Rendering in different portlets (liferay)

Tags: java, liferay-6, icefaces-1.8

I have two Portlets: 
the first contains: **datatable A**
and the second: **datatable B**.
The two portlets are shown in the same page.
I want to refresh the **datatable A** after I click on a command button in the **datatable B**.

The method called by the command button contains this code:

```
OnDemandRenderer onDemandRenderer = getRenderManager().getOnDemandRenderer("RENDER_GROUP");
onDemandRenderer.requestRender();
```

But it doesn't work.
Can anyone help me please? Some hints?
Thanks in advance for any help!!

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem using static variables.
Datatable A uses the dataModel object that is filled in this way in the managed bean:

```
dataModel=new ListDataModel(globalDD.getDetailsList());
```

where globalDD in the managed bean:

```
private GlobalDocumentDetails globalDD;
public GlobalDocumentDetails getGlobalDD() {
  return SessionBeanUtility.getGlobalDD();
}
public void setGlobalDD(GlobalDocumentDetails globalDD) {
  this.globalDD = globalDD;
}
```

And SessionBeanUtility.getGlobalDD() is

```
public static GlobalDocumentDetails getGlobalDD(){
    if (FacesUtil.getPortletSession().getAttribute(GLOBAL_DD_BEAN_KA, PortletSession.APPLICATION_SCOPE) == null)
    {
        new GlobalDocumentDetails();
        FacesUtil.getPortletSession().setAttribute(GLOBAL_DD_BEAN_KA, new GlobalDocumentDetails(), PortletSession.APPLICATION_SCOPE);
    }
    return (GlobalDocumentDetails)FacesUtil.getPortletSession().getAttribute(GLOBAL_DD_BEAN_KA, PortletSession.APPLICATION_SCOPE);
}
```

The datatable B contains the items of a shopping cart and the cart is a static object.
I use the code that i wrote in the question in the actionListeners methods of the two datatables to refresh both.